# Remove hyperlink of images and text, but keep links of certain websites - php

Tags: php

i want to keep images and text, but keep hyperlink of certain cites for example: twitter.com

i used this code

```
<?php

$Content = 'text <a href="https://www.somesite.com/" title="test"><img src="imagelink.jpg"/></a> some text <a href="https://www.twitter.com/rere" title="test">twitttter.com</a> other random text';

$keepImage = preg_replace('/<a.*?(<img.*?>)<\/a>/', '$1', $Content);
$allowed = array("twitter.com","t.co");
preg_match_all('/<\/?a[^>]*>/', $Content, $matches);
foreach($matches[0] AS $link){
    foreach($allowed AS $site){
        if(strpos($link, $site) !== false){
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $Content = str_replace($link, '', $Content);
}

echo $Content;
?>
```

The result is:

```
text <img src="imagelink.jpg"/> some text <a href="https://www.twitter.com/rere" title="test">twitttter.com other random text
```

but I want it to be:

```
text <img src="imagelink.jpg"/> some text <a href="https://www.twitter.com/rere" title="test">twitttter.com</a> other random text
```

with `</a>` to be a valid link.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your first `preg_replace()` is not being used as the following functions are all being called against `$Content`, not `$keepImage`.

Your regex in the `preg_match_all()` matches all the opening and closing anchor tags separately, so this is the var_dump of $matches -

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(49) "<a href="https://www.somesite.com/" title="test">"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "</a>"
    [2]=>
    string(52) "<a href="https://www.twitter.com/rere" title="test">"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "</a>"
  }
}
```

As only the third match contains an allowed string, the other three are replaced with your empty string `''`. You can change the regex to match the opening and closing tags plus everything in between -

```
preg_match_all('/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/', $Content, $matches);
```

The problem with this arrangement is that if the `$allowed` strings are contained anywhere within the match then the link will be allowed. For example -

```
<a href="https://example.com/some/url#twitter.com">some more text</a>
<a href="https://example.com">this is my fake twitter.com link</a>
```

would both be allowed. You will be surprised how quickly your users figure this out. A crude solution would be to include the protocol in the `$allowed` array and add another sub-group in the regex to capture the content of the href attribute.

```
<?php

$Content = <<<STR
twitter link with image <a href="https://twitter.com/POTUS"><img src="./some-image.png" alt="bl4h"></a>
text <a href="https://www.somesite.com/" title="test"><img src="imagelink.jpg"/></a> some text <a href="https://twitter.com/rere" title="test">twitttter.com</a> other random text
<a title="bl4h" href="https://twitter.com"><img src="./bl4h.jpg"/></a>
<a href="https://example.com/some/url#twitter.com">some more text</a> and some more text
<a href="https://example.com">this is my fake twitter.com link</a> and some more text
STR;

$allowed = array('https://twitter.com','https://t.co');

$Content = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/',
    function($match) use ($allowed) {
        if (strpos($match[2], '<img') !== false) {
            return $match[2];
        } else {
            foreach($allowed as $site) {
                if (strpos($match[1], $site) !== false) {
                    return $match[0];
                }
            }
            return $match[2];
        }
    },
    $Content
);

echo $Content;
```

will output -

```
twitter link with image <img src="./some-image.png" alt="bl4h">
text <img src="imagelink.jpg"/> some text <a href="https://twitter.com/rere" title="test">twitttter.com</a> other random text
<img src="./bl4h.jpg"/>
some more text and some more text
this is my fake twitter.com link and some more text
```